# Проблема со слайдером html/css

Tags: html, css, slider

Здравствуйте, у меня есть небольшой слайдер на css, возникла проблема:
Первый и второй слайд переключаются между собой без проблем, но после того как выбираю третий слайд, то переключатели перестают работать и менять слайды, помогите разобраться с проблемой, пожалуйста

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.slide-toggle {
  border: 0;
  clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);
  -webkit-clip-path: inset(50%);
  clip-path: inset(50%);
  height: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.sliders-block::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  left: 620px;
  top: 40px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 7px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.slider-img {
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.sliders-block .first-slider {
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, #f7e296 113px, #ffffff 113px);
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-top: 4px;
  padding-right: 60px;
}

.first-slider .slider-img {
  padding-left: 60px;
}

.first-slider .slider-info-block {
  padding-top: 80px;
  padding-left: 128px;
}

.first-slider .slider-info-block td {
  padding-right: 77px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.sliders-block .second-slider {
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, #f7e296 113px, #ffffff 113px);
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-top: 4px;
  padding-right: 60px;
  padding-left: 27px;
}

.second-slider .slider-img {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-left: 90px;
}

.second-slider .slider-info-block {
  padding-top: 80px;
  padding-left: 138px;
}

.second-slider .slider-info-block td {
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.third-slider .slider-img {
  padding-top: 64px;
}

.sliders-block .third-slider {
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, #f7e296 113px, #ffffff 113px);
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-top: 4px;
  padding-right: 60px;
}

.third-slider .slider-info-block {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  padding-top: 80px;
  padding-left: 45px;
}

.third-slider .slider-info-block td {
  padding-right: 45px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.slider-info-block h2 {
  font-family: 'gilroyextrabold', sans-serif;
  font-size: 47px;
  line-height: 55px;
  font-weight: 800;
  color: #000000;
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.slider-info-block p {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #464646;
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 44px;
  padding: 0;
}

.slider-info-block a {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'gilroyextrabold', sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 800;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-left: 45px;
  margin-bottom: 56px;
}

.slider-info-block a::before {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  content: '';
  width: 220px;
  height: 8px;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: #f0c52e;
}

.slider-info-block a:focus::before,
.slider-info-block a:hover::before {
  height: 40px;
}

.slider-info-block a:active {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.slider-info-block .headline {
  font-family: 'gilroylight', sans-serif;
  font-size: 36px;
  color: #000000;
}

.slider-info-block .description {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #464646;
}

.slider-info-block td:last-child {
  padding-right: 0;
}

.toggle-position {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 148px;
  right: 80px;
}

.toggle-position label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-right: 18px;
}

.button-1:checked~.toggle-position label[for='btn-1'],
.button-2:checked~.toggle-position label[for='btn-2'],
.button-3:checked~.toggle-position label[for='btn-3'] {
  background-color: black;
}

.sliders-block .slide {
  display: none;
}

.button-1:checked~.sliders-block .first-slider,
.button-2:checked~.sliders-block .second-slider,
.button-3:checked~.sliders-block .third-slider {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input class="slide-toggle button-1" type="radio" id="btn-1" name="toggle1" checked>
  <input class="slide-toggle button-2" type="radio" id="btn-2" name="toggle1">
  <input class="slide-toggle button-3" type="radio" id="btn-3" name="toggle1">
  <div class="toggle-position">
    <label for="btn-1"></label>
    <label for="btn-2"></label>
    <label for="btn-3"></label>
  </div>
  <section class="sliders-block">
    <section class="slide first-slider">
      <div class="slider-img">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x350" alt="Монопод">
      </div>
      <div class="slider-info-block">
        <h2>
          Делай селфи,<br> как Бен Стиллер!
        </h2>
        <p>
          Самая длинная палка для селфи доступна в нашем магазине.<br> Восемь (Восемь, Карл!) метров длиной и весом всего 5 килограмм.
        </p>
        <a href="#">Подробнее</a>
        <table>
          <tr class="headline">
            <td>8,5 м</td>
            <td>5 кг</td>
            <td>Карбон</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="description">
            <td>Длина палки</td>
            <td>Вес палки</td>
            <td>Материал</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section class="slide second-slider">
      <div class="slider-img">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x350" alt="Фитнес-браслет">
      </div>
      <div class="slider-info-block">
        <h2>
          Худеем<br> правильно!
        </h2>
        <p>
          Мотивирующие фитнес-браслеты помогут найти в себе силы не пропускать занятия и соблюдать диету.
        </p>
        <a href="#">Подробнее</a>
        <table>
          <tr class="headline">
            <td>48 часов</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="description">
            <td>Без подзарядки</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section class="slide third-slider">
      <div class="slider-img">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x350" alt="Квадрокоптер">
      </div>
      <div class="slider-info-block">
        <h2>
          Порхает как бабочка, жалит как пчела!
        </h2>
        <p>
          Этот обычный, на первый взгляд, квадрокоптер оснащен мощным лазером, замаскированным под стандартную камеру.
        </p>
        <a href="#">Подробнее</a>
        <table>
          <tr class="headline">
            <td>800 м</td>
            <td>50 м</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="description">
            <td>Дальность полета</td>
            <td>Радиус поражения</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </section>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Проблема в .third-slider .slider-info-block { position: relative; z-index: 2; } - очевидно. Из-за этого слайды перекрывают точки. Осталось понять зачем эти стили вообще нужны конкретно для этого слайда, вроде ничего не меняют.

Comment: Спасибо! Просто в оригинале там есть еще декоративные элементы из-за них нужен был z-index, сделал переключателям z-index больше и теперь ничего их не перекрывает.